# Reading and writing data in Python (Matlab user)

Tags: python

I am trying to get into Python from Matlab so, starting small, I'm looking at reading and writing data. I've been spoiled by Matlab's excellent self-contained documentation and am having trouble finding the best approach to follow in Python for what in Matlab is achieved mainly with fopen, textscan, fgetl, regexp, and fprintf. I've seen some advocate numpy.loadtxt (& savetxt) while others advocate a "with open(...) as f: for line..." approach -- the latter may be what I need in this case of reading a column of string headers followed by a matrix of floating numbers, both of unknown size. I've put together sample Matlab code that:

1. Reads the path and name of a file to be read, as noted in a text file, and combines them into a single string
2. Determines the number of headers in the file from 1, and size of the matrix of comma delimited floating data below the headers
3. Reads the headers and matrix in the file from 1, separated into two variables
4. Write the headers and matrix to another file

Some of these steps, for example 2-3, could be combined in practice but separating them here will help me with some distinct tasks. This is maybe more of a "please share with me best coding practices in Python for this generic task" rather than a very specific question but I expect this would be useful for other new Python users as well. Thanks for any specific Python code and/or references.

```
%%
function ReadWrite()
tic
f=readPaths();
[t,n]=pullSize(f);
[hdr,d]=readData(f,t,n);
writeData(hdr,d);
toc
end
%%
function f=readPaths
fid=fopen('Paths.txt','r');
f=textscan(fid,'%s%s','delimiter','\t','headerlines',1);
fclose(fid);
f=char(fullfile(f{1},f{2}));
end
%%
function [t,n]=pullSize(f)
n=0;
fid=fopen(f,'r');
l=fgetl(fid);
h=isempty(regexp(l,',','once')); % headers are not comma delimited
while h
    n=n+1;
    l=fgetl(fid);
    h=isempty(regexp(l,',','once'));
end
fclose(fid);
t=length(regexp(l,','))+1; % file is comma delimited
end
%%
function [hdr,d]=readData(f,t,n)
fid=fopen(f,'r');
hdr=textscan(fid,'%s',n);
d=textscan(fid,repmat('%f',1,t),'delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);
d=[d{:}];
hdr=[hdr{:}];
end
%%
function writeData(hdr,d)
fid=fopen('DataTest.csv','w');
for i=1:length(hdr)
    fprintf(fid,'%s\n',hdr{i});
end
fprintf(fid,[repmat('%.4f,',1,size(d,2)-1),'%.4f\n'],d');
fclose(fid);
end
```

Comment: you might want to also include the [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/matlab/info) tag for those users familiar with reading your `matlab` code

Comment: Thanks but I did originally and a moderator removed the matlab flag.

Comment: There is a code review stack exchange site for this sort of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I was originally poking around with the csv module and some other things you suggested but ended up using mostly numpy's load[save]txt along with standard Python's readline and some other miscellaneous libraries for certain things. I was just coming back to this today and it took me a while to figure out nested functions, read/write formatting and so forth but I replicated the code and it's only a bit slower than my Matlab version -- including here for posterity:

```
import numpy as np
import os
from itertools import islice
import time


def readwrite():
    tic = time.time()
    f = read_paths('Paths.txt')
    n = pull_size(f)
    hdr, d = read_data(f, n)
    write_data('Data_Py.txt', hdr, d)
    toc = time.time()
    with open('Runtime_Py.txt', 'w') as fid:
        fid.write("Elapsed time is %.6f seconds." % (toc - tic))


def read_paths(f):
    f = np.loadtxt(f, dtype='str', delimiter='\t', skiprows=1)
    return os.path.join(f[0], f[1])


def pull_size(f):
    n = 0
    with open(f, 'r') as fid:
        l = fid.readline()
        h = not(l.count(','))  # headers are not comma delimited
        while h:
            n = n + 1
            l = fid.readline()
            h = not (l.count(','))
    # t = l.count(',') + 1  # file is comma delimited
    return n


def read_data(f, n):
    with open(f, 'r') as fid:
        hdr = ''.join(list(islice(fid, n)))
    hdr = hdr.rstrip('\n')
    d = np.loadtxt(f, dtype='float', delimiter=',', skiprows=n)
    return hdr, d


def write_data(f, hdr, d):
    np.savetxt(f, d, fmt='%.2f', delimiter=',', newline='\n', header=hdr, 
comments='')

readwrite()
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something that you might want to use the Pandas library for. Pandas has a read_csv method which does exactly what it sounds like and stores the data in what is called a DataFrame which you can essentially think of as an excel spreadsheet.

http://pandas.pydata.org/

The functionality is similar to R's dataframes or the data.table package.

Comment: Thanks, I was googling pandas and saw some saying that it's much faster than numpy.load[save]txt so I might look into this more in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use csv module in the Python standard library to do this.

```
import csv

with open('path/to/file.csv', 'r') as f:
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(f)

with open('path/to/output.csv', 'w') as w:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(w, dict_reader.fieldnames)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(dict_reader)
```